# Run tests on dynamic file in cypress.io

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, mocha.js, cypress

I am trying to use [cypress](https://www.cypress.io) to test a large angular app that I have built. My requirement is that I load an expectation file into my test and then drive the test off this expectation file.

I have so far been unable to get this to work using various combinations of `cy.readFile()`,  `cy.fixture()`, and even `axios` to load the file via http.

The issue seems to be that I can't use these methods outside of `it()` and if I can't do that it means I can't loop through the data to create the its. I am trying to do something like the below... is this even possible in cypress? Am I missing something obvious?

Lets say my expectation looks like this:

```
{
    "mainPage": [1, 2, 3],
    "otherPage": [4, 5, 6]
}
```

I want my code to load it and go through the various pages:

```
describe(`Test the app `, function() {
    cy.readFile("path/to/expectation.json").then(function(expectation) {
        Object.keys(expectation).forEach(function(pageName) {
            it(`for page ${pageName}`, function() {
                gotoPage(pageName);
                var pageData = getDataFrompage();
                expect(pageData).to.equal(expectation[pageName]);
            })
        })
    })
})
```

This seems to me like a pretty obvious use-case so I'm confused why it appears to be so difficult :)

Answer (score 4):

I have a similar requirement, except I'm reading an application config file (which lives within the app assets folder).

I read it with a `require` like so,

```js
const runtimeConfig = require('../../../src/data/my-config');
```

This works well, I can then proceed to test with expectations based on the file contents.

So, your code would be something like this

```js
const expectation = require('path/to/expectation.json');

describe(`Test the app `, function() {
  Object.keys(expectation).forEach(function(pageName) {
    it(`for page ${pageName}`, function() {
      gotoPage(pageName);
      var pageData = getDataFrompage();
      expect(pageData).to.equal(expectation[pageName]);
    })
  })
})
```

---

**readFile()**

Trying `cy.readFile()`, you get get this error message

> Uncaught Error: Cannot call "cy.readFile()" outside a running test.

You can stop this error by wrapping the read in a  `before` like so

```js
let runtimeConfig;
before(function(){
  cy.readFile('./src/data/my-config.json').then( fileContents => {
    runtimeConfig = fileContents;
  })
})
```

but unfortunately Cypress does not wait for the read to complete before proceeding to test.

---

**fixture()**

I also tried the fixture pattern shown in **example.spec.js**

```js
context('Files', function(){
  beforeEach(function(){
    cy.visit('https://example.cypress.io/commands/files')
  })
  it('cy.fixture() - load a fixture', function(){
    // Instead of writing a response inline you can
    // connect a response with a fixture file
    // located in fixtures folder.

    cy.server()

    // https://on.cypress.io/fixture
    cy.fixture('example.json').as('comment')

    cy.route(/comments/, '@comment').as('getComment')

    // we have code that gets a comment when
    // the button is clicked in scripts.js
    cy.get('.fixture-btn').click()

    cy.wait('@getComment').its('responseBody')
      .should('have.property', 'name')
      .and('include', 'Using fixtures to represent data')
```

but could not get it to work with my config file even when copying it to the `/cypress/fixtures` folder.

Also, this feels a quite hacky - if I understand this code correctly, it is turning the file read into a pseudo route navigation so that Cypress can wait on it.

This pattern is complicated and certainly does not lend itself to the dynamic testing scenario you describe.

Answer (score 0):

1. Suppose, you have below data in expectation.json file.

   > ```
   > {
   >   "mainPage": [1, 2, 3],
   >   "otherPage": [4, 5, 6]
   > }
   > ```

Then your code would be something like this to create Test cases dynamically

```
const data = require("path/to/expectation.json");

describe('Test the app', function() {
   Object.keys(data).forEach(function(page, i){
      it(`Test Case For: ${page}`, function() {
        cy.log(data[page])
      })
   })
})
```

[image: See Output Below]